# Unable to run Virtual Network Editor

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I've downloaded and extracted the `vmnetcfg.exe` and `vmnetcfglib.dll` following [this guide](http://www.carbonwind.net/Virtualization/VMware-Player-Networking-Options/VMware-Player-Networking-Options.htm)

But when I click the file to open it nothing happens.
Running as admin doesn't work as well.

VMWare player 6.

vmnet extracted from workstation 10.

Running windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by downloading VMware 6.03 ([link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0))

And then downloading the missing `vmnetcfg.exe` & `vmnetcfglib.dll` from [HERE](https://ninety9names.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/download-vmnetcfg-exe-vmnetcfglib-dll-for-vmware-player-6-x-7-x/)